# Unexpected click event propagation to sibling when `label` parent contains `button` and `span` children

Tags: javascript, html, events, onclick, label

When a `label` element contains `button` and `span` children (all siblings), clicking the span unexpectedly also clicks the first button.

For example, here's a label that has 2 buttons and 2 spans as direct children, each of which has a single click event that displays an alert:

```js
btn1.addEventListener('click', function() { alert('btn1')})
span1.addEventListener('click', function() { alert('span1')})
btn2.addEventListener('click', function() { alert('btn2')})
span2.addEventListener('click', function() { alert('span2')})
```

```html
<label>
  <button id="btn1">Button1</button>
  <span id = "span1">Span1</span>
  <button id="btn2">Button2</button>
  <span id = "span2">Span2</span>
</label>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/uwp8b1o2/

Clicking on any button triggers that button's click event only (as expected). However:

1. Clicking on the first span also triggers the first button's click event
2. Clicking on the second span also triggers the click event of the first button (but not the second button or other span)
3. Changing the parent to "span" or "div" gets rid of the unexpected behavior-- it only seems to happen when the parent is a label

Tried on:

- Chrome 116.0.5845.140
- Safari 15.6.1

Online documentation of the `label` element says nothing about its child event propogation differing from that of other elements https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_label.asp

What the heck is going on?

Comment: That's the point of labels. Clicking on the label is equivalent to clicking on the button, checkbox, etc.

Comment: Use `event.preventDefault()` to prevent duplicate events.

Comment: If you couldnt click on a label for a checkbox, users would have to always aim the mouse/pointer inside the small checkbox square. Its a convenience for the label to forward the click event. It is surprising though that such behavior extends to buttons.

Comment: _"When a label element contains button"_ - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label#accessibility_concerns: _"Accessibility concerns - Interactive content: Don't place interactive elements such as anchors or buttons inside a label. Doing so makes it difficult for people to activate the form input associated with the label."_

Comment: @GetSet what is also surprising/confusing is that the "forwarded-click" behavior does not apply to button clicks-- in fact, reversing the children order (see https://jsfiddle.net/oa08b27L/) makes the behavior even MORE confusing: clicking on the 1st or 3rd (but not 4th) child will forward the click to the SECOND child! None of these comments (or their links) saying "well this is just how labels work" address the inconsistency in how different child types are treated. Best explanation imho is "behavior of interactive elements in labels is undefined"

Comment: @CBroe thanks but, imho, that documentation is incomplete and misleading. It should also say "and may lead to unexpected behavior" and explain that label behavior is not consistent across all child elements types. It is sometimes true that a click on the label will fire a click even on its first child, but that is not always true (see above comment + jsfiddle)

Comment: @mwag if the label has no explicit `for` attribute, then its first "labelable" descendant element becomes its _labeled control_. The first labelable element in your example(s) is the first `button` (in DOM order), and clicks on the spans simply bubble up to the label, which then in turn focusses its labeled control. https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#the-label-element

Comment: @CBroe I stand corrected. Thank you